# Reloading JSP Changes in Eclipse/STS

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, apache-tiles

I'm just getting into GAE and I'm using STS (derivative of Eclipse).  I'm currently getting a project set up to use Spring and Apache Tiles under GAE.  I've got it mostly configured properly and it seems to work.  My biggest problem is figuring out how others handle day-to-day developing in this kind of environment.

I make tons of changes to the front-end JSPs but so far it seems like I have to stop the GAE server and restart it every time I make a small change to a JSP.  Having to restart when I make changes to the controller is fine, but having to restart it for a simple JSP change is driving me crazy.

Is there a way to have the GAE environment reload JSP changes in Eclipse/STS?

Comment: I'm not aware of STS. Does the Google Plugin for Eclipse work with STS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Maven for AppEngine project, so whenever I build the project, there will be a project target directory generated/updated which is where the server will load the files from. When I tried to update my jsp/css/js files, I always open the file in that directory and update it there. Once I'm satisfied with the it, I will copy the changes to my source file.

Essentially, I think for you, you can find out where is your target directory, and try to edit your files from there.

I'm not sure if my workaround is suitable for you but maybe you can get one or two here.

Apart from that, there are people using JRebel which is a hotdeploy tool. There is a AppEngine version of JRebel there, but I suspect it is not free...

Comment: It is free for Scala, OSS projects and personal use

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a look at [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel). Even if it is commercial software, it will save you a lot of nerves for this kind of development

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parameter:

```
server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true
```

(Put it into `application.properties` if you use `spring boot`)